# How to vertically right <a> tag in the <div> block?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Here's the code:

**HTML**

```css
.a_btn_right{
        vertical-align: right;
    }
```

```html
<div class="a_btn_right">
        <a class="btn" href= "" >Read More</a>
</div>
```

But fail to make vertically right `<a>` tag in the `<div>`, any idea about how to make it happen?

Comment: Have a look at this fiddle, it shows all possible ways you can use to align center an element vertically: http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/FAwku/1/

Comment: @sumitbadaya it's cool, thx a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vertical-align: right;` properties is

```
vertical-align: baseline|length|sub|super|top|text-top|middle|bottom|text-bottom|initial|inherit;
```

to make text `right`, try:

```
text-align: right;
```

**or:**

```
float: right;
```

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**

```
.a_btn_right{
   width:100%;
}

.a_btn_right a{
   float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to :

```
<div class="a_btn_right">
    <a class="btn" href= "{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}" >Read More</a>
</div>
```

and css to

```
.a_btn_right{
   border:2px solid #000;
   height:300px;
   width:300px;
   text-align:left;
}
```

You can delete border,height and width;
See here: http://codepen.io/mhadaily/pen/OXGbYp

Answer (score 0):

```css
.a_btn_right{
   border:2px solid #000;
   height:300px;
   width:300px;
   text-align:left;
}
.a_btn_right a{
  float:right;
}


Try This
```

```html
<div class="a_btn_right">
    <a class="btn" href= "#" >Read More</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always go down the Flexbox route which is also a great thing to start adding into your CSS.

All you'd need to do is edit your CSS  to:

```
<style>
    .a_btn_right{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
</style>
```

If you're concerned about if it would work on all browsers you can check here as a reference: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

This website is also good for double checking any type of code you'd like to use on your website however, I strongly believe Flexbox is the way forward. It is also a good way to turn non responsive builds into a responsive website design.